# Ошибка в DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Таблица не загружается, в консоль выводит ошибку:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'nTf' of undefined

Таблица:

```
 <table id="person" class="table display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="head" width="80">Id</th>
            <th class="head" width="80">Type</th>
            <th class="head" width="80">Actions</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th class="head" width="80">Id</th>
            <th class="head" width="80">Type</th>
            <th class="head" width="80">Actions</th>
        </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

JS:

```
     var table = $("#person").DataTable( {
        ajax: '/dcm/list_settings.php?settings_form=person&data=json',
        async: false,
        processing: false,
        serverSide: true,
        stateSave: true,
        columns: [
            { data: 'id'},
            { data: 'name'}
        ],
        columnDefs: [{
            targets: -1,
            data: null,
            defaultContent: '<a href="#" class="edt"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"></i></a><a href="#" class="del"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i></a>'
        }]
    });
```

PHP:

```
if ($_GET['data'] == 'json'){
$sql = "SELECT id, `name` FROM person";
$rows = $db_ad->GetAll($sql);
$result = array();
foreach($rows as $key => $row){
    $result[$key]['id'] = $row['id'];
    $result[$key]['name'] = $row['name'];
}
$data = array('data' => $result);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
die;
}
```

json:

```
 {"data":[{"id":"1","name":"CEO"},{"id":"2","name":"Group leader"},{"id":"3","name":"Assistance"},{"id":"4","name":"Sponsor"},{"id":"5","name":"Helper"},{"id":"6","name":"Visitor"},{"id":"7","name":"Judge"},{"id":"8","name":"Suplier"}]}
```

Comment: навскидку разное количество колонок в html  и результатах Ajax и не правильный формат данных в JSON. Добавьте лучше вместо кода PHP то что у вас возвращает функция PHP

Comment: Количество колонок тут роли не играет. на самом деле изначально было так:             columnDefs: [{
                targets: -1,
                data: null,
                defaultContent: '<a href="#" class="edt"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"></i></a><a href="#" class="del"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i></a>'
            }]

Comment: Функция php возвращает данные в правильном формате, в точности как в документации.  Но я не вижу аякс запроса в браузере